# Trouble setting up FTP (vsftpd) connection with server

Tags: networking, server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm trying to transfer files from my Windows 10 laptop to my Ubuntu Server (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS), and I'd like to use an FTP connection. I'm kind of knew to this, so I don't entirely know what I'm doing. I followed [this guide](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-vsftpd) and I am using WinSCP to connect (or trying to lol). [This image describes my WinSCP connection attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Rh8.png). The username I'm using is my personal account, and the password is the password for that account. The IP is the local IP since I'm on the same network as the server. I've tried miscellaneous fixes (such as adding that username to that one file (can't find it now) or changing various settings in /etc/vsftp.conf) and spent a couple hours on it but honestly I'm stuck. Any pointers and tips on how to get this running would be much appreciated!

Edit: [This is the error I get when I try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQtPQ.png)

Comment: Is your server on the local network or over the internet? There are a lot of different ways to transfer files over a network and FTP may not be a good choice especially since files are sent across FTP unencrypted, which can expose your data.

Comment: It is local rn, but I wouldn't mind being able to do it remotely. Personally I don't particularly care if the data itself is being sniffed (its just minecraft plugins lol), unless I'm ignorant to really sensative metadata or smt

Comment: Why are you trying to set up an insecure FTP, when  Ubuntu comes with a built-in secure SSH/SFTP server?

Comment: well frankly cause idk what I'm doing and was unaware of that lol. Do you know of any good resources for me to learn about that stuff and implement it?

Answer (score -1):

Alright I got it to work. I had SSH set up on a different port (i.e. 6700). So I set up my WinSCP connection with that port (6700) and connected using SFTP instead of FTP.